# cmake find_package for libxml2 doesn't return valid header directories

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, include, libxml2

I'm on ubuntu and I've installed gcc, cmake, libxml2-dev and I've this CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
find_package(LIBXML2 CONFIG)

include_directories(${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_libraries(${LIBXML2_LIBRARY})

add_executable(testusage testusage.cpp)
```

I run "cmake ." OK, and then make VERBOSE=1 it gives compilation error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target testusage
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/testusage.cpp.o
/home/a/proj/mynet/mytest/cpp3p/useXml2/testusage.cpp:1:9: fatal error: libxml/parser.h: no such file or directory
 #include<libxml/parser.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/testusage.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/testusage.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Seems that "include_directories" didn't add any "-I" option into Makefile. How could I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me, as soon as I use `find_package(LibXml2)` instead of `find_package(LIBXML2 CONFIG)`. According to [cmake-documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/find_package.html?highlight=find_package#id3), the config-mode tries to find a configuration-file, provided by the package:

> Config mode search attempts to locate a configuration file provided by
>   the package to be found. A cache entry called _DIR is
>   created to hold the directory containing the file. By default the
>   command searches for a package with the name . If the
>   NAMES option is given the names following it are used instead of
>   . The command searches for a file called
>   Config.cmake or -config.cmake
>   for each name specified. A replacement set of possible configuration
>   file names may be given using the CONFIGS option.

So it seems to me, as if `libxml2` does not provide such a config-file.

**testusage.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

int main(void)
{
  xmlParserNodeInfo info;

  std::cout << std::hex << &info << std::endl;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
find_package(LibXml2)

include_directories(${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_libraries(${LIBXML2_LIBRARY})

add_executable(testusage testusage.cpp)
```

**calling and building it**

`$ cmake .`

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so (found version "2.9.4") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/test/build
```

`$ make --trace`

```
Makefile:176: target 'cmake_check_build_system' does not exist
/usr/bin/cmake -H/tmp/test -B/tmp/test/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
Makefile:83: update target 'all' due to: cmake_check_build_system
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /tmp/test/build/CMakeFiles /tmp/test/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: target 'CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/all' does not exist
make -f CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/depend
CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/build.make:112: target 'CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/depend' does not exist
cd /tmp/test/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /tmp/test /tmp/test /tmp/test/build /tmp/test/build /tmp/test/build/CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target testusage
make -f CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/build
CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/build.make:62: update target 'CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/testusage.cpp.o' due to: ../testusage.cpp /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/SAX.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/SAX2.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/dict.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/entities.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/globals.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/hash.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/list.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/threads.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/valid.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xlink.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlIO.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlautomata.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlerror.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlexports.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlmemory.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlregexp.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlstring.h /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlversion.h CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/flags.make
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_echo_color --switch= --green --progress-dir=/tmp/test/build/CMakeFiles --progress-num=1 "Building CXX object CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/testusage.cpp.o"
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/testusage.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -o CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/testusage.cpp.o -c /tmp/test/testusage.cpp
CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/build.make:95: update target 'testusage' due to: CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/link.txt CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/testusage.cpp.o CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/build.make /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_echo_color --switch= --green --bold --progress-dir=/tmp/test/build/CMakeFiles --progress-num=2 "Linking CXX executable testusage"
[100%] Linking CXX executable testusage
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/testusage.dir/link.txt --verbose=
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_echo_color --switch= --progress-dir=/tmp/test/build/CMakeFiles --progress-num=1,2 "Built target testusage"
[100%] Built target testusage
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /tmp/test/build/CMakeFiles 0
```

`$ ./testusage`

```
0x7ffe0c7a5360
```